# Issue with SHAREit in ANDROID LOLLIPOP

Tags: applications, shareit

I am trying to use SHAREit app, if I am in sending mode. It prompts to choose the user to whom u wanna share data/apps. After choosing the end user it keeps preparing itself for sharing data however it remains in same status, data transfer remains null. Pls help how to overcome this issue as this is a usual issue.....

Comment: Facing the said issue after moto g2 upgraded to lollipop

Comment: You should probably contact the developer of the app.

Comment: Are you both using same version of ShareIt?